# HTML Submenu hides when I hover on them

Tags: html, css

Below are the HTML and CSS used. When I hover on the Parent Links, Submenu opens perfectly. But when I hover on the Submenu, it just disappears. I knew it was my CSS causing some issue. I tried few tricks but doesn't seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_navigation">
        <ul id="header_topbar_ul">
            <?php
            global $db;
            $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE modules_status='1' AND modules_show_in_menu='1' AND modules_parent_id='0' ORDER BY modules_order ASC");
            if($db->num_rows()){
                foreach($db->rows() as $menu){
                    $modules_id = $menu["modules_id"];
                    $modules_name = $menu["modules_name"];
                    $modules_slug = $menu["modules_slug"];
            ?>
            <li id="header_<?php echo $modules_id; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $modules_slug; ?>" title="Dashboard"><?php echo $modules_name; ?></a>

                <?php
                    $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE modules_parent_id='$modules_id' AND modules_status='1' ORDER BY modules_order ASC");
                    if($db->num_rows()){                    
                ?>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <?php
                            foreach($db->rows() as $submenu){
                                $modules_id = $menu["modules_id"];
                                $modules_name = $menu["modules_name"];
                                $modules_slug = $menu["modules_slug"];
                        ?>
                            <li id="header_<?php echo $modules_id; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $modules_slug; ?>" title="Dashboard"><?php echo $modules_name; ?></a></li>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>

            </li>

            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header_navigation{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
}

#header_topbar_ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul ul.submenu{
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}

#header_navigation > #header_topbar_ul > li > a:hover + ul.submenu {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
}

#header_navigation > #header_topbar_ul > li > ul.submenu li{
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 140px;
}

#header_navigation > #header_topbar_ul > li > a:hover, #header_navigation > #header_topbar_ul > li > a > ul.submenu{
    display: block;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Since it's an HTML/CSS issue, why not give us the resultant HTML code instead of the PHP? (i.e. Load the page in your browser, go to View Source, and copy that markup instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the submenu's `display` to `block` in the following situation:

1. `#header_navigation > #header_topbar_ul > li > a:hover + ul.submenu { display: block; background: #000; }` - when a link followed by a submenu is hovered over
2. `#header_navigation > #header_topbar_ul > li > a > ul.submenu{display: block; background: #000; }` - when a submenu is wrapped in `<a>` (never happens)

You might want to add the following:

1. `ul.submenu:hover {display:block; background: #000;}` - when the sumbenu itself is hovered over